# Inherit search view filter from stock picking to contacts models - Odoo v13 Community

Tags: inheritance, filter, searchview, stock, odoo-13

I'm trying to add a filter from **stock picking** (Ready, Done ...), into **Contacts** filter.

Specifically, trying to inherit from *stock.picking* the filter that i need, to add it into *res.partner* (search view contacts).

```
So, I've created a new model.
```

Like this .. (.py):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Part of Odoo. See LICENSE file for full copyright and licensing details.
from odoo import models, fields, api

class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    available = fields.Many2one('res.partner',
                             string="Available",
                             domain="[('state', 'in', ('assigned', 'partially_available'))]")
    done = fields.Many2one('res.partner',
                                string="Done",
                                domain="[('state', '=', 'done')]")
```

view (.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_res_partner_filter_inherit">
            <field name="name">res.partner.filter.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_res_partner_filter"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search>
                    <filter name="available" string="Ready" domain="[('state', 'in', ('assigned', 'partially_available'))]" help="Assigned Moves"/>
                    <filter name="done" string="Done" domain="[('state', '=', 'done')]" help="Pickings already processed"/>
                </search>
            </field>
        </record>

</odoo>
```

image:

[The filter has been added ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCSlR.png)

But, An error occurred while selecting the filter

```
Erreur:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1280, in search_read
    return self.do_search_read(model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1299, in do_search_read
    return Model.web_search_read(domain, fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=sort)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\models\models.py", line 39, in web_search_read
    records = self.search_read(domain, fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 4841, in search_read
    records = self.search(domain or [], offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1618, in search
    res = self._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\res_partner.py", line 710, in _search
    count=count, access_rights_uid=access_rights_uid)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 4386, in _search
    query = self._where_calc(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 4115, in _where_calc
    e = expression.expression(domain, self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\osv\expression.py", line 675, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\osv\expression.py", line 856, in parse
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field 'state' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('state', 'in', ['assigned', 'partially_available']) on res_partner (ctx: )>"
```

I'm not really sure, but it seems like it enters into a neverending loop when I call it from the search view.

So, I don't really know what's wrong with it.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You got error because there is no state field in res.partner model.

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: You need to tell exactly what you want to do?Your code is not complete.Where is your res.partner model?

Comment: i want inherit a filter from stock picking to contacts filter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want but try this.Add state field in res.partner model.

```html
class respartner(models.Model):
    _inherit= "res.partner"

    state = fields.Selection([('draft','Draft'),
            ('waiting','Waiting'),
        ],default='draft'
        )
<odoo>
<data>
<record model='ir.ui.view' id='view_res_partner_filter'>
    <field name='name'>res.partner.select.inherit.base.partner.filter</field>
    <field name='model'>res.partner</field>
    <field name='inherit_id' ref='base.view_partner_form'/>
    <field name='arch' type='xml'>
        <field name="category_id" position="after">
            <field name="state"/>
    </field>
  </field>
</record>
<record id="view_res_partner_filter_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.res.partner.filter.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_res_partner_filter"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <filter name="salesperson" position="before">
                <filter string="Draft" name="state" domain="[('state', '=', 'draft')]"/>
                <filter string="waiting" name="state" domain="[('state', '=', 'waiting')]"/>
            </filter>
        </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem

Comment: @ZakariaHamid.You want to add filter in contact view,right? So you have already checked state field exit or not?And what do you mean you want to inherit filter from stock picking to contact filter? I think your problem is easy but you need to tell clearly.That why nobody is answering your question.Thanks.

Comment: in filter of stock picking, There are 6 states of customer delivery (Draft, waiting, confirmed, assigned, done, cancel), i need to inherit this filter to search view in filter of contacts.

Comment: @ZakariaHamid. I edited my code.Don't forget to add some state in state field .I tested for some demo.Try this.

Comment: thanks so mutch, but the 'state' who i want, the state from delivery state in model stock picking.. stock -- delivery  -- filter

Comment: If you want to use field from another model, you need to have connection with stock.picking model. Which field has connect with stock picking model in res.partner. If you don't have , you need to create one and how to link between them upon which domain.

Comment: how can i create the connection with stock.picking and res.partner?